# Map without key on non markup return

Tags: javascript, reactjs

If I have this snippet of code for instance, how can I map through this without getting the following error?

> Each child in an array or iterator should have a unique "key" prop.

```
  this.setState({
        campus: e.target.value.map(school => school.value)
      });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use the index and set it as key,Since [array.map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) has a second optional parameter as index which will be unique.[**Note**: use this if you don't have a id or something unique]

Since in react you need to have a key property this is not an error but its a warning .

keys usually help react to identify which element has been updated. You can read more on this [List and Keys in React](https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html)

```js
this.setState({
    campus: e.target.value.map((school,index) => {value: school.value, key: index})
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

In react it will look for the key property. To solve your issue its best to bind the key property in UI and map the array object accordingly, you can then just map the data as per it instead of just picking the value from student.

If our student object does not have unique property you can use Symbol or have some node modules like cuid to generate unique keys.

Answer (score 0):

you should add a key property:

```
this.setState({
    campus: e.target.value.map(school => {value: school.value, key: school.id})
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe if You're using e.target.value so You expect it to be an array to map already (because .map() is an array method)?

I don't think it's possible to get an array from e.target.value but anyway You have an answer in official React Documentation, it's about You can use default item index as a key:

```
const todoItems = todos.map((todo, index) =>
  <li key={index}>
    {todo.text}
  </li>
);
```